# Do W3C Thing Description forms require an op key?

Tags: iot, json-ld, web-of-things

In the W3C WoT Thing Description specification (https://w3c.github.io/wot-thing-description/#td-vocab-forms--InteractionAffordance), it says that interactions have a forms array that can contain different forms with different op keywords. Why are those op keywords required though?

Comment: https://w3c.github.io/wot-thing-description/#td-vocab-op--Form?

Comment: Yes, however it sadly does not explain why those are used.